# Hopback filter mesh size (microns)

Tags: hops, filtering, hopback

I am building a Hopback (sort of DIY). Found this on the interwebz:
[image]

Wondering if 40 micron (approx. 350 mesh) which comes with this filter is not too fine of a filter for a hopback?

Or should I use something like the below in the filter housing instead:
[image]

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Are you using your hopback for flower hops or pellet hops? For flower hops this seems fine, for pellet hops it is too coarse. 300-400 micron is what I find on diverse homebrew forums, for handling pellet hops.

Comment: Just what I thought. I got the filter housing which comes with 40 micron filter and I also ordered this - https://ae01.alicdn.com/kf/Hdcadc1704c1d45e8849157c4b5438d71w.jpg which is 400 micron. Thanks for your comment.